# HTML/CSS: @media for exact screen size

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to understand CSS a bit and I'm currently somewhat stuck with @media rules and screen sizes. I want to change the background color depending on the current resolution. Here's the CSS:

```
section {    
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin-right: 10px;
    background-color: brown;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 9999px) {
    section {
        background-color: red;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {   
    section {
        background-color: blue;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    section {
        background-color: yellow;
    }  
}
```

Just using a simple

```
<section>
    bla
</section>
```

HTML code. Here's a w3schools tryit link since you can easily resize your viewport.
https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FDW9EOFLTCX6
However, it does not work like I'd want it to.
For the yellow background (< 500px), it stays yellow until 500 included.
For the blue background (>= 500px && < 1000px), it stays blue until 1000 included.
For both cases, the color jump occurs at 501 and 1001 respectively. If I adjust the width values to 499 and 999 respectively, however, the color jumps suddenly happen at 499 and 999 instead.
It seems I cannot understand how to get the change to happen at exactly 500 and 1000. Or is it just a problem with the editor I posted?

Comment: might be related to what browser you are using. mine works as expected

Comment: you can also specify ```@media screen and (max-width: 500px) and (min-width: 1000px)```

Comment: After change to 499 and 999, it happens exactly at 500 and 1000 for my browser (Chrome 57).

Answer (score 1):

It depends where you want the 'jump' to happen, but assuming you want the background to be `yellow` at `500px` and `blue` between `501px` and `999px`, you can simply use the following:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 501px) and (max-width: 999px) {
    section {
        background-color: blue;
    }
}


@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    section {
        background-color: yellow;
    }  
}
```

Don't forget that you can also use `min-width` as well as `max-width`, and that media queries will always take priority **sequentially from top to bottom**.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

i thing the perfect responsive media query tag is this one

```
 @media (min-width:1600px) and (max-width:3600px) {
.model-student-gallery .modal-lg {
    width: 60%;
} 
}
```

you want to wright to css according to media screen  .
Try it it's helpful for creating  responsive layout .